# Implement ProgressBar with content information which is transferred

Tags: android

How to add a progressbar when we copy a big file from one location to another with the details of the content that what extent of the file hasbeen moved?
Please suggest me some answer.

Answer (score 1):

refer to this:

[progress bar](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ProgressBar3.html)